# How to plot a ellipse node with igraph?

Tags: r, igraph

It seems no such questions has ever been asked in SO. However, the help page of `igraph` on customizing node shapes is rather vague. Can someone provide a complete example of customizing node shape in `igraph`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not say what language you use, so I am going to respond in R.

The shapes that are built-in can be listed with `shapes()`. Unfortunately, ellipse is not among them.  The help page `?shapes` gives a few examples of how to add additional node shapes - a triangle, a star and adding an image.  The response below is a straightforward modification of the example code for adding a triangle.   There are several functions for drawing ellipses. I used the one from the `plotrix` package.

```
library(igraph)
library(plotrix)

## Need a graph as an example
set.seed(1)
N10 = erdos.renyi.game(10, 0.31)

## Function for plotting an elliptical node
myellipse <- function(coords, v=NULL, params) {
  vertex.color <- params("vertex", "color")
  if (length(vertex.color) != 1 && !is.null(v)) {
    vertex.color <- vertex.color[v]
  }
  vertex.size <- 1/30 * params("vertex", "size")
  if (length(vertex.size) != 1 && !is.null(v)) {
    vertex.size <- vertex.size[v]
  }

  draw.ellipse(x=coords[,1], y=coords[,2],
    a = vertex.size, b=vertex.size/2, col=vertex.color)
}

## Register the shape with igraph
add_shape("ellipse", clip=shapes("circle")$clip,
                 plot=myellipse)

## Plot it, with different sizes and colors to illustrate
plot(N10, vertex.shape="ellipse", vertex.color=rainbow(vcount(N10)),
     vertex.size=(2:11)/2)
```

Et voila.

[image: Elliptical Nodes]

Comment: Thanks @G5W. Yes I meant for R and `igraph`. But for a directed graph and edges with arrow, the elliptic nodes are overlapping with the arrow heads.

Comment: OK, I figured out. I have to define custom clip function for elliptic shape.